# From table to array jquery objects

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am attempting to gather values of custom data attributes using `each`.

Here's what I have so far
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bluey/vG36j/15/)

**Heres the JQ/JS**

```
var multi = $('.till__tablepanel_table_0_row__ticket');
var myarray = [];

$.each(multi, function (index, item) {
    myarray.push( {name: 'ticket_row_num', value: $(item).data('ticket_row_num')} ); 
    myarray.push( {name: 'itemtitle', value: $(item).data('itemtitle')} );
    myarray.push( {name: 'row_quantity', value: $(item).data('row_quantity')} ); 
    myarray.push( {name: 'rowunitprice', value: $(item).data('rowunitprice')} );  
    myarray.push( {name: 'row_total', value: $(item).data('row_total')} ); 

  //  myarray.push( {name: 'measure_type_is_grams', value: $(item).data('measure_type_is_grams')} ); 

});

alert(myarray);
```

The issue is I am getting `[object, Object]` being returned, and I don't know why.

I am terribly unfamiliar with arrays in JS/JQ and I am trying to work this out to not much avail.

Comment: You can override its `toString` method to make it output what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have an array of objects, which when converted to string gives the o/p [object, Object].. instead try `alert(JSON.stringify(myarray));` - it will give a json representation of the object.

It is happening because the default `toString()` implementation of an object will return `[object Object]`